# cakePHP after returning from a form all variables are lost

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Using cakePHP v2.3.4.
Revised question after debugging what goes on, I have the following problem any variable is lost after returning from a form [post]. I have tried to store some information in a Global variable, but that didn't solve my problem either. Why are all variables lost after returning from the form?

Any suggestion how I could solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried `Configure::write()` & `Configure::read()`?

Comment: Yes, Configure::write() works only for the controller you use. It seems you can't change the Global variable somewhere in a different controller so the value changes. it 'defaults' back to what you have set it in the bootstrap.php file.

Comment: HTTP is a stateless protocol. You cannot store variables between requests without sessions or something similar.

Comment: Do you only have to pass a single variable? And if so, is the other controller visited via a link? You may consider to pass that variable via the URL, e.g. `/controller2/view/123?myvar=foobar`

Comment: @Nick, to help us understand a little better, you might want to explain why you want to do such a thing? What variable do you want to pass?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Session configuration in /app/Config/core.php or the session configuration in your php.ini file and make sure you're using sessions stored on the server itself. (Likely you're using the php.ini.)

Comment: Hi Ryan, as I mentioned, the sessions are related to a cookie, when cookies are disabled in your browser, the session->write/read are useless! therefore I am not able to pass through my variables. I have set it to php and/or cake, checked if the session files are written, which they are! but again, I discovered that no cookie, no session. Hence my attempt to use a global variable, but that one doesn't allow to have a new value written to it!

Comment: @Sam Delaney, I am still a novice, but I discovered that when I have cookies disabled that I can't use any more sessions $this->Session->write/read. I then tried to solve my problem with setting a global variable in the bootstrap and use Configure:: write/read. Again no result. Then I decided to use in this other controller to load the Model and grab again from the DB the necessary fields, so far so good, problem almost solved, but I need to use 2 fields in the same controller but with different function. It seems my problem is now different then my original question. Still very frustrating.